# xcode ipad simulator - several issues

Tags: xcode, ipad, simulator

I'm seeing some unexpected behaviour in the ipad simulator for xcode 4.5.2. If anyone can offer any suggestions that would be appreciated.

1) when my app is run, the ipad is always starting off in portrait orientation, instead of landscape - even if I set the simulated metrics->orientation to landscape.

2) in project->summary->ipad deployment info->launch images, the 4 icons all show a yellow warning triangular flat saying "the size of the current image does not match the recommended size of AAAA x BBBB pixels". I did not import any launch images. All 4 icons show a black block in portrait orientation, including the two landscape ones. No such warnings are displayed in the iphone section.

Do I have something set up incorrectly? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the files names are Default-Portrait.png and Default-Landscape.png according to [this instructions](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/launchImages.html).

If you name the file as Default.png the simulator recognize the file as the default launch image, but Xcode fails to recognize this file name and and produces this warning.